# Identifying projection being used in figure

Tags: coordinate-system

I would like to use the projection being used in this figure.

Does anyone know which one it is?

[From plant stress page](http://www.nasa.gov/topics/earth/features/plant-stress.html)

[image: http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/711179main1_drought_ESI-2011-226x.JPG]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attached screenshot is an exported map from ArcGlobe, which uses a [cube projection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q8000000sv000000).

[image]